# Sólo actualiza los valores en el primer click button - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Dispongo a cargar en varios inputs los valores de un objeto el cual está cargado en un array.

**¿Por qué me los carga solamente para el primer click en el button "Ver disco", y no para los siguientes clicks?** He de decir que la búsqueda de los datos la realizo mediante el campo input "Nombre".

Por ejemplo: inserto el disco A, el disco B y el disco C; pongo seguidamente en "Nombre" el valor "B", y me carga los valores del disco "C". Siempre me recarga los valores del último elemento.

**Código Javascript:**

```
   this.existeDisco = function (nombreRecibido){
        var existe = false;
        for(var i=0; i<this.arrayDiscos.length; i++){
            var nombre = this.arrayDiscos[i].nombre;
            if(nombre == nombreRecibido)
                existe = true;
        }
        return existe;
    }


//Función para ver los datos de un disco. Lo veremos mediante el campo "Nombre".
function verDisco(){
    var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    //Comprobamos si existe el disco en nuestra tienda...
    if(miTienda.existeDisco(nombre)){
        //Cargamos los datos del objeto cuyo nombre = nombre en los diferentes campos del formulario.
        for(var i=0; i<miTienda.arrayDiscos.length; i++){
            //Guardamos los valores en variables.
            var nombre_objeto = miTienda.arrayDiscos[i].nombre;
            var cantante_objeto = miTienda.arrayDiscos[i].cantante;
            var anio_objeto = miTienda.arrayDiscos[i].anio;
            var estanteria_objeto = miTienda.arrayDiscos[i].estanteria;
            var tipo_objeto = miTienda.arrayDiscos[i].tipo;
            var prestado_objeto = miTienda.arrayDiscos[i].prestado;
            //Asignamos los valores a los campos inputs.
            document.getElementById('nombre').value = nombre_objeto;
            document.getElementById('cantante').value = cantante_objeto;
            document.getElementById('anio').value = anio_objeto;
            document.getElementById('estanteria').value = estanteria_objeto;
            document.getElementById('tipo').value = tipo_objeto;
            document.getElementsByTagName('prestado').value = prestado_objeto;
        }
    }else{
        //Si NO EXISTE ningún disco con ese titulo/nombre, mensaje.
        document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML="NO EXISTE NINGUN DISCO CON EL NOMBRE '"+nombre+"'.";
        document.getElementById("nombre").focus();
    }
}
```

**Código evento JS:**

```
document.getElementById('ver').addEventListener('click', verDisco, false);
```

Comment: Ahora me he dado cuenta que es cierto lo que dices. ¿Cómo podría validarlo para que inserte los inputs del nombre que quiero buscar?

Comment: Tu función `existeDisco` debe de tener justo la validación que buscas para encontrar el nombre del disco en tu arreglo de discos

Comment: Inserto la función en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifica tu función existe disco, para que mates dos pájaros de un tiro y evites repetición innecesaria de código:

```
this.existeDisco = function (nombreRecibido){
    for(var i=0; i<this.arrayDiscos.length; i++){
        var nombre = this.arrayDiscos[i].nombre;
        if(nombre == nombreRecibido)
            return this.arrayDiscos[i];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Y en tu método de `verDisco()` haz estos ajustes:

```
function verDisco(){
    var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    var disco = miTienda.existeDisco(nombre);
    if(disco !== false){
        document.getElementById('nombre').value = disco.nombre;
        document.getElementById('cantante').value = disco.cantante;
        document.getElementById('anio').value = disco.anio;
        document.getElementById('estanteria').value = disco.estanteria;
        document.getElementById('tipo').value = disco.tipo;
        document.getElementsByTagName('prestado').value = disco.prestado;
    }else{
        //Si NO EXISTE ningún disco con ese titulo/nombre, mensaje.
        document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML="NO EXISTE NINGUN DISCO CON EL NOMBRE '"+nombre+"'.";
        document.getElementById("nombre").focus();
    }
}
```

De esta forma tu método `existeDisco()` ya te regresa el arreglo donde se encuentran los datos de tu disco que estás buscando, en caso de que no haya encontrado nada, el ciclo termina y regresa `false` y eso lo usas dentro de tu función `verDisco()` para asignar el valor de tu disco a tus inputs, o avisar al usuario que no encontró información del disco buscado.